# Relational operator operating on strings in c++ not working as expected

Tags: c++

```
int main() 
{ 
    string s1("z"); 
    string s2("ab"); 
    if(s1 > s2) cout << s1 << " is greater than " << s2 << endl;
    cout << ("z" > "ab") << endl;
    return 0; 
 }
```

And the output is

```
z is greater than ab
0
```

I am a bit confused as in the 3rd statement s1 > s2 does a lexographical compare and the result is expected, but the statement 4 returns a 0 value.

Thanks, as it's driving me crazy

Update ------

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{ 
    string s1("z"); 
    string s2("ab"); 
    cout << &s1 << " " << &s2 << endl;
    if(s1 > s2) cout << s1 << " is greater than " << s2 << endl;
    cout << ("z" > "ab") << endl;
    cout << ("ab" > "z") << endl;
    cout << &("ab") <<  " "  << &("z") << endl;
    return 0; 
}
```

The above code helped me.

Comment: 4 is the same lexicographical compare using *string-literals*.

Comment: `"z"` and `"ab"` are *string-literals* created in read-only memory. Your comparison simply compares a pointer to `"z"` and a pointer to `"ab"`. (most likely the same pointers used to initialize `s1` and `s2` -- as the compiler likely only creates a single literal for each and uses it multiple times as required in your code)

Comment: @David "created in read-only memory" - do wish this myth about "read-only memory" would go away. Many architectures have no notion of such a thing, and you certainly can't create values on a ROM chip. The C++ (and C) Standard says that attempts to modify string literals are undefined - that's all.

Comment: @NeilButterworth - you are correct and I concede the point. Should read "Created in read only memory on most architectures, but is implementation defined."

Comment: @David But it's not read-only memory (after all, the compiler emitted code to place values there), it's memory protected by the OS from  writes after process initialisation. Which I admit doesn't have a catchy name :-)

Comment: @NeilButterworth, that's somewhat a sticky-wicket. Within an ELF, the `.rodata` section where *string literals* go is very much read-only memory. Now other executable place the data in mutable regions, but a blanket statement that where they go is not read-only is no more correct than saying they all go in read-only, so both require a few additional weasle-words or qualifications. But I get your point and I agree with it, but telling the mass of new C programmers that *string literals* should be treated other than read only may do more harm than good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
cout << ("z" > "ab") << endl;
```

is equivalent to

```
char const* s1 = "z";
char const* s2 = "ab";
cout << (s1 > s2) << endl;
```

That expression compares just two pointers. The result of that is not guaranteed to be `true`. It is not guaranteed to be `false` either. The result depends on where the compiler allocates memory for the string literals.

Comment: Thanks. That was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`"z" > "ab"` compares C-string literal, so it compares pointers, not content.

Which is, pedantically, not well defined BTW (`std::less` would be).

Comment: It's not comparing string literals, it's comparing string objects.

Comment: @nicomp In the context of this answer, no, it isn't.

Comment: @nicomp: OP does both, `s1 > s2` and then `"z" > "ab"` expecting the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the “string” literals that you use aren’t really strings: they degenerate into pointers to `char`. That’s the horrible C legacy. Yuck.

If you want to compare strings, you must be explicit about it:

```
assert(string_view("z") > string_view("ab"has ));
```

Prefer asserts to debug output, too. They make it clear what you observe, without having to provide any output nor use English prose to describe what you get. Your question could then be minimized as “why does the assertion in 4 hold?”.